# iOS device token not regenerated after migration from APN to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I created an APP for both iOS and Android and I used APN to get deviceToken for iOS and GCM for Android. I decided to migrate to firebase to make token management easier. I noticed a issue just for iOS application and I was wondering if someone else encountered it too.
When I migrated iOS app to firebase, token was not regenerated unless the app was reinstalled.  I follow the [firebase guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm) to do it but with no result.
Someone else has this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Our team faced with it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

1. I switch off and switch on capabilities
   [image]
2. I restarted XCode
3. I put **FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType** to **prod** and now all seems to work

   func application( _ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data ) {
           FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
           FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
       }